# How to use document.getElementById() in React Test cases (JEST+ ENZYME)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a document as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p id="para">My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using below code in my React App

```
const fieldElement = document.getElementById(fieldError);
```

Now how do i test this particular line in my React test case scenario

```
it("should provide fieldElement for the id", async () => {
  let fieldError = "para"
  // Need to write test for document.getElemetById here
  });
```

Can someone please shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `.createRef()` for getting the reference to the DOM element: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html